# html string not populating properly in textarea field

Tags: jquery, html

I need to be able to render some HTML tags inside a textarea (namely , , , ) but textareas only interpret their content as text. Expected string as below

```
<strong><span style=""background-color: yellow"">I AGREE </span>TO THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS OF THE CONSUMER INSTALLMENT LOAN AGREEMENT (this “Contract”).<br>By electronically signing the Contract by checking the box above and then clicking the “Get Loan Now” button below, you (i) acknowledge receipt of this Contract, with all necessary spaces filled in, (ii) certify you fully read and understand the Contract and you agree to comply with and be bound by its terms, and (iii) you reaffirm consent to the use of electronic records for all transactions with LendNation and all documents relating to those transactions.</strong>
```

but its replacing with below

```
\u003cstrong\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\"background-color: yellow\"\u003eI AGREE \u003c/span\u003e "TO THE TERMS OF THE VOLUNTARY ACH CREDIT AUTHORIZATION AGREEMENT(the "ACH Credit Authorization")".\u003c/strong\u003e\u003cbr\u003e "By electronically signing the ACH Credit Authorization by checking the box above and then clicking the "Get Loan Now" button below, you certify you fully read and understand the ACH Credit Authorization provision of the Contract, and you agree to comply with and be bound by its terms."\u003cbr/\u003e"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with a textarea, but take a look at the `contenteditable` attribute.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    This text can be edited by the <strong>user</strong>.
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content